# on one image movement, two view should move according to finger movement, is any way to do this?

Tags: android, user-interface

I had setOnTouchListener on one image, it moving according to my finger movement. Can i call a framelayout according to movement of that image. Our requirement is as i move image from top to bottom it should come with that image.

```js
 final ImageView swipedown_test = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.swipedown);

        swipedown_test.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        origXCord = swipedown_test.getX();
                        origYCord = swipedown_test.getY();


                       final float x = v.getX();
                       final float y = v.getY();

                        dX = x - event.getRawX();
                        dY = y - event.getRawY();

                        mLastTouchX = x;
                        mLastTouchY = y;

                        System.out.println("original x value :" +x);
                        System.out.println("Original y Value :" +y);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    
                    // Want here to show framelayout with this image
                       
                        final float x1 = v.getX();
                        final float y1 = v.getY();

                        System.out.println("On moveStart X Value :" +x1);
                        System.out.println("On moveStart Y Value :" +y1);

                        // Calculate the distance moved
                        final float dx1 = x1 - mLastTouchX;
                        final float dy1 = y1 - mLastTouchY;

                        System.out.println("movement in x : "+dx1);
                        System.out.println("Movement in y : "+dy1);
                        v.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
                        v.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  
                        v.setX(origXCord);
                        v.setY(origYCord);
                        
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
               
              return true;
            }
        });
```